# Netcat send only 7k bytes when it is written to a script over ethernet

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, netcat

I've tried to send a file in Ubuntu with 8k bytes with netcat from a pandaboard to a pc. It works with these commands when I execute them manually in the terminal:

```
nc -6 -l 2345 > uplinkFile &
ssh panda@<ipaddr> "dd of=uplinkFile if=/dev/urandom bs=1024 count=8"
ssh panda@<ipaddr> "nc -6 <PcIp>%eth0 2345 < uplinkFile"
```

but when I write these commands into a script, it only transfer 7k and stop then and there are no errors. Has anyone any idea what the reason is for that problem?

my script:

```
nc -6 -l 2345 > uplinkFile &
ssh panda@<ipaddr> "dd of=uplinkFile if=/dev/urandom bs=1024 count=8"
ssh panda@<ipaddr> "nc -6 <PcIp>%eth0 2345 < uplinkFile"
```

result:

```
user@user:~/Documents$ ./NCtest.sh 8
8+0 records in
8+0 records out
8192 bytes (8.2 kB) copied, 0.00527954 s, 1.6 MB/s
user@user:~/Documents$ ls -l uplinkFile 
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user user 7168 Sep  8 12:29 uplinkFile
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem, I switched from nc to ncat and now it is possible to send bigger files